# Pandas replace negatives with mean by category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I'd like to replace all negative values from my column with mean by category.
I can easily find a mean for each category.
It's like 
`train_df1.groupby(train_df1['item_category'])['item_cnt_day'].mean()`.

```
    item_category
Access            1.115664
Books             1.087056
CD                2.199036
CD games          1.361757
Card              1.421528
Consoles          1.298143
Consoles Games    1.242093
Delivery          8.261742
Phone games       1.232323
Name: item_cnt_day, dtype: float64
```

Also I have some negative values in 'item_cnt_day' column(which is impossible as it's kinda difficult to sell negative amount of milk or smth else). 
And my 'idea' is to replace negative values from `'Books'` category with mean by `'Books'`, `'Consoles'` with mean by `'Consoles'` and so on. 
Actually, I don't know if it is better to count mean with these negative values or not...

Can you please help me. It's pandas.DataFrame btw :)

Comment: So the first thing to do is to identify WHERE all the values are negative, then replace them with the mean, right? Have you tried that? What did you get?

Comment: You should attempt to figure out why the negative values are being generated. If they are correctable, fix them. If they are not, probably replace them with NaN and then the mean. You do not want out-of-bounds values to skew your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to think about it is that negative numbers a na's. So let's do it:

```
train_df1[train_df1 < 0] = np.nan
```

Now lets make a new column with the mean by category:

```
grouped = train_df1.groupby('item_category')['item_cnt_day'].mean()
```

Make a new column with the mean of the category:

```
train_df1['category_mean'] = train_df1.merge(grouped, left_on='item_category', right_index=True)
```

Now fill the na values:

```
train_df1.item_cnt_day.fillna(train_df1.category_mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.transform` to add the mean values as a column to the DataFrame:

```
train_df1["groupby_mean"] = train_df1.groupby(train_df1['item_category'])['item_cnt_day'].transform("mean")
```

And then use numpy's `where` to apply the conditions:

```
train_df1["item_cnt_day"] = np.where(train_df1["item_cnt_day"]>=0, train_df1["item_cnt_day"], train_df1["groupby_mean"])
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, a better way to handle/replace negative values with `mean` in single line of code

```
train_df1['item_cnt_day'] = train_df1.groupby('item_category')['item_cnt_day'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x < 0, x.mean(), x))
```

I had a similar issue and tried @neves method but it caused missing values issue for a larger dataframe with multiple data types.